# Undefined index error

Tags: php

This undefined index error pops every time:

```
Notice: Undefined index: vehicle_id in
C:\xampp\htdocs\TaxiLocator\php\retrive.php on line 39

Notice: Undefined index: model in
C:\xampp\htdocs\TaxiLocator\php\retrive.php on line 42
```

But only two of the variables are unidentified; the other two variables are displayed on the table.

Is there something wrong with my MySQL db?

**php code**

```
<?php
while($vehicle_table=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$vehicle_table['vehicle_id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$vehicle_table['latitude']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$vehicle_table['longtitude']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$vehicle_table['model']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

`vehicle_id` is declared as an `int` type, while `latitude`, `longitude`, and `vehicle_id` are declared as `double`, and `model` is declared as `varchar`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you please add a little more code? How are you populating `$records`, for example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Give me your sql query string

Comment: `print_r($vehicle_table)`